# Questions about an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $\alpha>0$.  Is the following inequality $$\log^\alpha(1+x)\leq x$$ true for $x>0$? What about when $\alpha>1$?

Comment: Is "a" a power or a base indication (logarithm base "a") ?

Comment: The following inequality is not true suppose for some $x$ we have $log(1+x)\geq 2$ now choose large enough $\alpha$ to contradict that , as for $2^{\alpha}>x$

Comment: For $0 < \alpha < 1$ the inequality fails for small $x > 0$. For $\alpha = 1$ it holds for all $x > 0$. For $\alpha > 1$ the function $x \mapsto x - \log^{\alpha}(1+x)$ attains its maximum at $x = \alpha-1$. So the question is for which $\alpha > 1$ we have $\log^{\alpha} \alpha \leqslant \alpha-1$. It's not hard to see that it holds for $1 < \alpha \leqslant 3$, and a little further. Doesn't hold for $\alpha \geqslant 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=\ln 1(1+x)-x \implies\frac{1}{1+x}-1=-\frac{x}{1+x} < \forall~ x \ge 0$$ So $f(x)$ is a decreasing function for $x\ge 0$, then $$f(x) \le f(0) \implies f(x) \le 0 \implies \ln(1+x) \le x.$$ 
 $$a>1 \implies \ln^{a}(1+x) < \ln(1+x) \le x.$$

Comment: It will be nice if you clarify how for $\alpha>1$, how $\ln^\alpha(1+x)\leq \ln(1+x)?$

Answer (score 0):

*Counterexample*:

$\ln(1+\mathrm e)\approx 1.313\;$ and $\;1.313^6>1+6\cdot 0.313=2.878>\mathrm e$.

Comment: then is $\ln^\alpha(1+x)\leq \alpha x$ true?

Comment: This probably depends on $\alpha$ and $x$.